# How to open the hsql gui for a db which is embedded in a java program?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, user-interface, hsqldb

I have embedded hsql db in my program and I automatically create tables in my *.script file. However, I want to have the hsql gui, so that I can better check if everything is correct?

How to load the gui for my embedded db file?

Comment: I think the only way is to start HSQLDB as a server from within your application. Then you can also connect from a second JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method call below can be used, with `yourdb` as the name of your mem: database:

```
org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing.main(new String[] { "--url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:yourdb", "--noexit" });
```

The method should be executed in its own thread, so that it does not stop your program.